# How to email Graduate Director that I will not attend (F1 student)

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

I have made some wrong decisions during my PhD studies in a US university (let's call it University X). One year ago, I got another admit(let consider this University Y)  when I got admit to University X. I didn't have fund to join university Y, thats why I got accepted the offer from university X.

Now university Y offered me admission plus funds  and I accepted it, even the admission procedure has been completed. I have not transferred my sevis  no yet.

After a lot of thinking I have decided that I will not transfer to another university, rather I will complete my PhD here.

How can I email to the graduate director of University Y that I want to cancel my admission there and I do not want to join their program?

Comment: "After a lot of thinking I have decided that I will not transfer after all; rather, I will complete my PhD here.  Nevertheless I would like to thank you and the admissions committee for the offer."

Comment: Are you asking how to write the email, or are you asking about something else in the process? If it's just about writing the email, then the comment from @aparente001 is a good example of how to be clear and professional.

Comment: So you have already accepted the new offer but now you want to reverse the decision?

Comment: @Dawn yes, And the admission procedure is completed too.

Comment: I feel like in this case it helps to give a more compelling reason than "I changed my mind." Also, I would challenge you to make sure your first and second instincts to apply to the new school and accept their offer are not better than this new "cold feet" feeling.

Comment: @Dawn I did it because of financial reasons and a little better reputations. Now I find that the financial supports are same rather I would lose a year. What should I write?

Comment: You would lose a year because they won't count the classes you have already taken? Did you try to negotiate this with them?

Comment: Nope I didn't. I also passed the qualifying exam here. They don't know that i will be a transfer student, its because i got the admission at the two universities same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree - you have to tell Y. I agree with the above but add capitals to Admissions Committed.

Dear Professor X

Thank you very much for the offer of funding to complete my PhD with [name of uni]/your Faculty/Department [match to the Director's level of appointment].    After some thought, I have decided, respectfully, not to accept the offer.

I remain though very grateful for your consideration and I would like, through you, to convey my thanks to the Admissions Committee for their support.

With kind regards,
Sincerely,
ZZ

Comment: You could add something like "I have learned (belatedly) that my current courses/work will not transfer to your program, and so I must regretfully withdraw my earlier acceptance." This would possibly replace the second line of the first paragraph, or go at the end of the first paragraph.